# Elastic Search - how can we calculate age in years between given and dynamic field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have below piece of code,

GET patient/_search { "query": { "range" : { "birthDate" : { "lte" : "now-20y/d" } } } }

Instead of now function, I want some dynamic value(2019-01-01 01:00:00.000) and then calculate years

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gte (Greater Than or Equal To) or gt (Greater Than)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#range-query-field-params) parameters to construct the query you are looking for.

Looking at your query you want a *list of patients who were born before 20 years* *from today's date*, in that case your query would be as follows.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "1999-11-14 01:00:00.000",     <--- Note this (Exactly 20 years from today)
              "lte": "now"                         
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now if you want list of patients born between `1985` and `2015`, your query would be in the below manner.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "1985-01-01 01:00:00.000",
              "lte": "2015-01-01 01:00:00.000"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thx kamal for your quick response but I want something like this, where patients who are 16 years older as of (2019-01-01) and that is dynamic it can be 16 or 20 or 25... I want patient's age

Comment: I want list of patients who are older than 20 years

Comment: Can I do something like this, this is giving me error,  GET  patient/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "birthDate" : {
                "lte" : "2019-01-01 01:00:000 -(20y/d)"
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: @zeba, I think the only way to do that via elasticsearch is to write a custom script. The one you have would simply return the documents. Give me few mins, I will update the response.

Comment: yeah I want the documents only but with an age of  20 years as of  '2019-01-01'...

Comment: Documents with an age of 20 as of `2019-01-01`, won't you get it from using the above answer. Your query would return you the docs of people having `age == 20` with what I've shared. Age would be w.r.t today's time right i.e. `now`??

Comment: yes ,it will return the documents but the only problem with the above approach is that , we have to provide the years for calculating 20 years age as of '2019-01-01' i.e, '1999-01-01' in the range query.  Can't we do it dynamically by providing just the years ?  GET  patient/_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "birthDate" : {
                "lte" : "'2019-01-01'-(20y/d)"
            }
        }
    }
}    will this work?

Comment: @zeba, Nope, I don't think what you are asking is possible. Only way would be to come up with a script but I don't think that would be efficient. I'd suggest you to make use of range query as most use cases would be filled by it.

Comment: yeah true,I figured out too and it seems not possible. Thanks for the feedback.